# How to read Assembly output generated by Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, assembly

I have the following C++ code:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    i = 1111;
    j = 2222;

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to view to what Assembly code this C++ code compiles to, so I chose the following option:

[image]

This option will output each C++ statement and directly under it the Assembly instruction(s) it corresponds to. But there are some C++ statements that don't corresponds to any Assembly instructions (for example: `int i;`). So I want to make sure that my following assumption is correct when reading the generated Assembly code:

[image]

Comment: Declaration of variabled `i` and `j` doesn't involve any instruction. It just makes the compiler make sure it marks the same address memory in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int i; int j;` are just variable declarations.. they are not even being initialized with the declaration, and hence in that sense, there is no explicit assembly instructions for those two lines.. But do note that the local variable declaration does lead to allocation for these local variables on the stack.

And yes, for the latter part of your question, `mov DWORD PTR_i$[ebp], 1111` only correspond to `i = 1111;`.

Comment: I meant does these three C++ statements corresponds to this single Assembly instruction, or does the first two C++ statements does not corresponds to any instructions?

Comment: `mov DWORD PTR_i$[ebp], 1111` only corresponds to `i = 1111;`

Comment: @joseph_m The declarations inform the compiler that it needs to reserve some space on the stack (or possibly just in a register) for those values. Declarations *can* result in assembly output -- for example if you declare a variable of a type with a default constructor, that constructor will be called. In this case, however, the declarations do nothing directly to the assembler output other than to change how much the stack pointer gets moved.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, you are correct. But if I create a new object (for example: `MyClass object1;`), the Assembly instructions corresponding to `MyClass object1;` will be displayed directly under it, and so I will know that these instructions corresponds to this statement. But I was just wondering if Assembly instructions can correspond to multiple C++ statements and not just one.

Comment: @joseph_m Sometimes, but it's more typical for multiple assembly instructions to correspond to one line of code.

Comment: @cdhowie If sometimes multiple C++ statements can corresponds to one set of Assembly instructions, is there a way I can know which corresponds to which? I mean the Assembly output generated by Visual C++ does not display that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think (for educational purposes) you should put those statements in a function and call the function from main and then (in the main function):

```
sub esp, 216                ; 000000d8H
```

becomes:

```
sub esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
```

and:

```
lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-216]
```

becomes:

```
lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
```

What is happening is that those instructions are reserving memory in the stack for i and j. So there are machine instructions (that will always be there except usually with other values) but you need to understand what is happening to understand what the instructions are. The 216 value will be used in the function containing the definition of i and j (assuming that there are no other definitions).

Note that the mov instruction that sets a value for "i" is using the ebp register. That register points to the stack. So I think you can assume that instruction is the only instruction.